# Magento 2 translate the .pdf invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, translate

I've set up a **Magento 2.3.0** shop, and I have also translated it. Everything seems fine on the front-end, but one part that I can't get translated, are the `.pdf` invoices. I have tried to add those words from the invoice into the translate `.csv` as well, but nothing is working, the invoice is still in English.

Comment: Try if changing the locale of your admin user and then re-generating the pdf makes a difference.

Comment: I have upgraded, compiled, deployed, reindexed, clean and still nothing..

Answer (score 1):

This is a magento2 bug
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4409

you can fix it by adding this code to any of your module's di.xml files

```
<type name="\Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface">
    <plugin name="mage_localeresolver_reload" type="Magento\Framework\Translate\Locale\Resolver\Plugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```